# LDAP Search json output

Tags: mule

In my mule flow I have an LDAP Paged Result Search as below. I want to get the output in json. I am getting back an ArrayList.

```xml
<flow name="ldapsearchFlow1" doc:name="ldapsearchFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="3555" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <ldap:paged-result-search config-ref="LDAP" baseDn="${xxx.ad.base}" filter="(objectClass=*)" pageSize="100" doc:name="LDAP">
        <ldap:attributes>
            <ldap:attribute>uid</ldap:attribute>
            <ldap:attribute>cn</ldap:attribute>
        </ldap:attributes>          
    </ldap:paged-result-search>
     <ldap:ldap-entry-to-ldif doc:name="ldap1"/>             
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON" />       
</flow>
```

Output is as below. I also dont need count , attribute count etc.

```
���sr�java.util.ArrayListx����a��I�sizexp��%w��%t�W{"dn":"CN=aaronj,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=org","attributes":{"count":1},"attributeCount":1}t�W{"dn":"CN=abbasa,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=org","attributes":{"count":1},"attributeCount":1}t�X{"dn":"CN=abbottl,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=org","attributes":{"count":1},"attributeCount":1}t�\{"dn":"CN=abeyrathnep,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=org","attributes":{"count":1},"attributeCount":1}t�Z
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your config related to the usage of `ldap-entry-to-ldif`:

- it converts a **single** LDAP entry to LDIF, but you use it to process a **collection** of results from `ldap:paged-result-search`. You need to either pick one LDAP entry from the search result (with a MEL expression transformer) or use `ldap:lookup` to return a single LDAP entry.
- it converts an LDAP entry its LDIF representation, which is a `String`. You then serialize this String as JSON. I think you need to pick one, either replace `ldap-entry-to-ldif` with `ldap-entry-to-map` so it can properly be serialized to JSON or remove the `json:object-to-json-transformer` and let your flow return the LDIF representation. Because you stated that you want to remove some values from the final representation, I feel that you're more interested in the JSON representation than the LDIF one. In that case the former approach is what to do: after the `ldap-entry-to-map`, you could then use a MEL expression transformer to filter the keeps you don't want, prior to JSON serialize the map.